# React Redux with hooks - authentication and protected routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using React with hooks, react-redux and redux-thunk and I'm not sure if I made the authentication correctly. In Main.js I'm calling an action called `checkIfLoggedIn()`. This is the Main.js content:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.checkIfLoggedIn();

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
                    <Navbar/>
                    <div className={'container-fluid'}>
                        <Route exact path={'/'} component={(Dashboard)}/>
                        <Route exact path={'/sale'} component={(Sale)}/>
                        <Route exact path={'/settings'} component={(Settings)}/>
                        <Route exact path={'/login'} component={(Login)}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    checkIfLoggedIn
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

This is the code of `checkIfLoggedIn()`

```
import {SET_ADMIN, SET_LOGGED_IN} from "./types";
import axios from 'axios';

export const checkIfLoggedIn = () => async dispatch => {
    const adminToken = window.localStorage.getItem('admin_token');
    if (adminToken === null)
        dispatch({
            type: SET_LOGGED_IN,
            payload: false
        });
    else {
        try {
            const r = await axios.get('/users/me');
            const data = r.data;
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ADMIN,
                payload: data
            });
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LOGGED_IN,
                payload: true
            });

        } catch (e) {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LOGGED_IN,
                payload: false
            });
        }
    }
};
```

And my initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    currentAdmin: {
    },
};
```

Now, I'd like to make a ProtectedRoute that will Redirect me to the Login route when I'm not logged in. I wanted to make something similar in the Login component, that would Redirect me to the `'/'` route if I'm logged in.

But in both cases, my prop isLoggedIn is initially set to false, and gets updated after few milliseconds. This is my Login component code that didn't work as expected:

```
const Login = props => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    dispatch(checkIfLoggedIn());

    useEffect(() => {
            setRedirect(props.isLoggedIn);

    }, [props.isLoggedIn]);

    return redirect ? <Redirect to={'/'} /> : (
    /* the login form code */
    )
}
```

The form is displayed for a moment, and after that I'm redirected to the main route. How can I prevent displaying the form? And how can I make a PrivateRoute waiting a moment to receive all the props and getting the initial isLoggedIn status?

Comment: So do you only want to redirect if the user is not logged in?

Comment: If a logged in user enters (manually) to the /login route I want to redirect him to the main route. If a logged out user enters any route I want to redirect him to the /login route.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the context of what you are doing, but here are my thoughts.  In your useEffect, the isLoggedIn boolean seems to be controlling the redirect boolean, which may be causing unwanted side effects.

Try this instead

```
const Login = props => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    dispatch(checkIfLoggedIn());

    useEffect(() => {
            // If user is not logged in, redirect them
            if (!props.isLoggedIn) {
            setRedirect(true)
     }

    }, [props.isLoggedIn]);

    return redirect ? <Redirect to={'/'} /> : (
    /* the login form code */
    )
}
```

If you are using react-router, and you export this component usint the `withRouter` higher order component, it may be better to use `history.push` for what you are trying to accomplish

```
const Login = props => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    dispatch(checkIfLoggedIn());

    useEffect(() => {
            // If user is not logged in, redirect them
            if (!props.isLoggedIn) {
            props.history.push('/redirectRoute')
     }

    }, [props.isLoggedIn]);

    return redirect ? <Redirect to={'/'} /> : (
    /* the login form code */
    )
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you, but this didn't work. After adding `if (!props.isLoggedIn){setRedirect(true)}` I'm always redirected, even if I'm not logged in. `props.isLoggedIn` comes as false, and then, after a few milliseconds it comes again as true. But using your code I'm instantly redirected.

Comment: Oh I must have misunderstood, I thought that you did always want to be redirected if you are not logged in